# How to find out when images cache expire?

Tags: browser, website

Is there way to find out how long a webserver set the expiration time (Max-time) for image files when you browse a site?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to look for a Headers that server sends in you response to image request.

Usually you can see, something like this in headers:

```
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 13:05:04 GMT
```

With no specific cache control headers. Which gives you browser opportunity to make subsequent requests with header:

```
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 12 Nov 2012 13:05:04 GMT
```

and keep file in cache as long as forever, while server keeps returning `304 Not Modified`.

To watch the headers you need any kind of Web-debugger, which can be a browser extension (like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox) or a separate application like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: In Fiddler, look at the Caching response inspector. This Inspector consults the Expires and Cache-Control headers and if they're missing, computes the heuristic expiration time using the RFC2616 algorithm.

Comment: Which can be a browser extension.. or simply the default browser dev tools, see network tab after pressing `cmd+opt+i`